# need an adjective to describe something important but not appropriate (see specific example)

Tags: adjectives

What would be a "right" adjective for the following sentence?
The sought-after adjective should denote the **necessity** of the matter but downplay its **significance** for the time being.

job hunter: I would like to discuss the issue of compensation during my phone interview with the hiring manager.

recruiter: I think it's best to focus the discussion primarily about the job for now. Compensation is a(n) _____ issue at this stage of the conversation with the manager.

a few options below, but none seems spot-on:

```
accessory/supplementary: additional ?
unnecessary: (I think this is a "wrong" choice of word in this context)
peripheral/tangential: maybe ?? but seems to imply the non-necessity of the matter
```

Any better suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You consider the issue to be **premature** at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is ancillary or secondary. Ancillary would suggest it is not the main point but absolutely necessary. Secondary makes the point about being non-central a bit stronger.